# Given my reward for a stupid question in photo, and my lack of reward for expertise in Java, can you tell me what is broken here?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, bounties, question-quality

I'm an experienced Java developer. I get a lot out of Stack Overflow, but when my answers are offsite, I don't ask.

I'm a noob in photography. I asked [a really basic question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/47945/travis-wellman?tab=questions) which, really, if I had clicked around in Wikipedia a little more, I would have known. Now I have over 150 reputation in photo.stackexchange, which I'm minimally invested in, for one stupid question.

Some of [the questions I asked in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413900/travis-wellman?tab=questions) are still unanswered (and indeed I still want answers for) and I get very few upvotes on SO. I still have just 19 rep there.

I'm just a professional doing my work. I am not going to spend hours (on the clock) racking up points to gain badges and privileges on a Q&A website. SO should be designed to recognize people like me.

Something is definitely broken. Can you tell me what? PEBKAC? Do I really need to learn how to game the system before it will reward me?

Comment: What "reward" are you looking for? rep really only gives you the ability to moderate other posts, which if you're interested in, you'll have to earn that privilege, but otherwise i don't see much point in you worrying over rep. Having more rep isn't going to get your questions answered.

Comment: It's a failing of the system that you are not rewarded with more reputation for posting a lot of questions. Quantity is definitely one metric that needs to be looked at in a serious fashion before it drives away more users from posting their questions

Comment: "Some of the questions I asked in Stack Overflow are still unanswered" - really? You have 7 questions and they each have **at least one answer**.

Comment: I really think this guy is a troll.  Source: "SO should be designed to recognize people like me."

Comment: You know, if you're an experience Java developer, you can also easily rack the point by answering *some* Java questions, provided that it's a high quality enough answer...

Comment: @AndrewT. True, I understand how I could get more points on SO, but what's frustrating is not how few I have there, because, as kevin-b said, I can use the site perfectly well with just a few points. The thing that seems to me to be 'broken' is that a poorly researched 'noob' question got so many points so quickly. There is a clear imbalance.

Comment: @DavidPostill not all answers are accepted because they may not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing that is broken here in my own humble opinion, is your perspective.

Simple questions that have value for others tend to get lots of upvotes because people can easily understand what exactly is being asked and think "Right, I wonder too", then upvote. Complicated questions, on the other hand, usually get fewer votes because only those who are really experts can judge the quality of the question, and if it really got value for others.

That's the case all around Stack Exchange, as far as I can tell. Quick example: [How can I automatically square-crop an image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50718/how-can-i-automatically-square-crop-an-image) - complicated question, that people simply can't judge, thus they do not vote.

True, it can be frustrating to not get answer to your questions, but it's really not limited to Stack Overflow, or for Stack Exchange in general. The only way to get 100% response is to hire a programmer, though even this can't guarantee the quality of the help you'll get.

Comment: Okay, so you may say that people on photo.stackexchange disagree with me about the value of the question I asked there. That's fair.

Answer (score 3):

The quality of your questions should be raised a little higher than what is shown to us now. The answers have plentiful amounts of upvotes because they are of high-quality.

High-quality questions will attract lots of users and of course, upvotes, like your so-called "noob" question for Photography. That question is high-quality, which attracted at least 5,000 views and has a current score of 31. So basically, just make better questions. You should view some highly upvoted questions to see what they have and you don't. Also, read the Help Center articles about asking to improve your questions and experience.

Comment: The photo question really wasn't high quality. It was not well researched.